# Permutations how to eliminate with certain rules

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I need to create a list with six elements $x$, $y$, $z$, $w$, $u$, $t$.

After this, I should print all of the possible permutations of the elements with length $3$ which follows this rule:

> The element "$u$" should not be after the element "$t$".

Has someone idea how should I start?

Comment: x, y, z, w, u, t is six elements... Also, by "print", do you mean with a computer program?  I think the simplest way is, by putting down all combinations, and then just crossing out the ones which have "tu" in them.

Comment: I have to do it in Wolfram Mathematica.

Answer (score 0):

Assign a number to the letters:

x = 1, y = 2, z = 3, w = 4, u = 5, z = 6.

Now suppose you have the first letter to be the hundred, the second one to be the tens and the third one to the units. Digits cannot be repeated.
This means that, for example, the number 324 is equal to the combination "zyw".

Then it's possible to find all the possible lists with 3 elements with this algorithm from Maple:

`N:=0:
for A from 1 to 6 do
    for B from 1 to 6 do
        if not(B=A) and not((A=6) and (B=5)) then
            for C from 1 to 6 do
                if not(C=A) and not(C=B) and not((A=6) and (C=5)) and not((B=6) and (C=5)) then
                    N:=N+1;
                end if;
            end do;
        end if;
    end do;
end do;
V:=Vector(N):
X:=0:
for A from 1 to 6 do
    for B from 1 to 6 do
        if not(B=A) and not((A=6) and (B=5)) then
            for C from 1 to 6 do
                if not(C=A) and not(C=B) and not((A=6) and (C=5)) and not((B=6) and (C=5)) then
                    X:=X+1;
                    V[X]:=A*100+B*10+C;
                end if;
            end do;
        end if;
    end do;
end do;
convert(V,list);`

There's 108 of them and here they are:

123, 124, 125, 126, 132, 134, 135, 136, 142, 143, 145, 146, 152, 153, 154, 156, 162, 163, 164, 213, 214, 215, 216, 231, 234, 235, 236, 241, 243, 245, 246, 251, 253, 254, 256, 261, 263, 264, 312, 314, 315, 316, 321, 324, 325, 326, 341, 342, 345, 346, 351, 352, 354, 356, 361, 362, 364, 412, 413, 415, 416, 421, 423, 425, 426, 431, 432, 435, 436, 451, 452, 453, 456, 461, 462, 463, 512, 513, 514, 516, 521, 523, 524, 526, 531, 532, 534, 536, 541, 542, 543, 546, 561, 562, 563, 564, 612, 613, 614, 621, 623, 624, 631, 632, 634, 641, 642, 643

All you have to do is convert them back from numbers to letters and you're set. Hope that helped.